# Unprocessable Entity: 422 while uploading file Asynchronously using filepond in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, filepond

I'm using [filepond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/) to upload my files to the server using [Laravel filepond Backend package](https://github.com/Sopamo/laravel-filepond#filepond-setup).

However, while uploading files using [Filepond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#introduction) Asynchronously using `XMLHttpRequest`. I noticed the following error pops up in the console.

> Getting **422 (unprocessable entity)** Error in console.

**File:** `Sopamo\LaravelFilepond\Http\Controllers\FilepondController.php`

```
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->file(config('filepond.input_name')); // $input = null
```

Below is the value getting from debugging the `$request` parameter in the `upload` method.

```
$request->files->parameters["filepond"]->test: false
$request->files->parameters["filepond"]->originalName: "originalFileName.pdf" //this is filename
$request->files->parameters["filepond"]->mimeType: "application/pdf"
$request->files->parameters["filepond"]->error: 0
$request->files->parameters["filepond"]->*SplFileInfo*pathName: "C:\xampp\tmp\php16E1.tmp"
$request->files->parameters["filepond"]->*SplFileInfo*fileName: "php16E1.tmp"
```

My `config\filepond.php` is the same as [Sopamo/Laravel Package config file](https://github.com/Sopamo/laravel-filepond/blob/master/config/filepond.php).

Below is my configuration:

```js
FilePond.registerPlugin(
    FilePondPluginFileEncode
);

FilePond.create(document.querySelector('input[type="file"]'));

FilePond.setOptions({
    server: {
        url: '/filepond/api',
        process: '/process',
        revert: '/process',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    }
});

FilePond.parse(document.body);
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" name="filepond" required multiple>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-validate-size/dist/filepond-plugin-file-validate-size.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-file-encode/dist/filepond-plugin-file-encode.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery-filepond/filepond.jquery.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**File:** `routes\web.php`

```
Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
  Route::post('/process', [FilepondController::class, 'upload'])->name('filepond.upload');
  Route::delete('/process', [FilepondController::class, 'delete'])->name('filepond.delete');
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a name attribute value to `file` to my file input element. From `<input type="file" name="filepond">` to `<input type="file" name="file">`.